# How to switch repositories in Android Studio?

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, svn-update

I had initially checked out code from repository A. But due to maintenance tasks, we had the code moved to a new repository B.

When I try to update/commit my code I get the below error:

```
svn: 'http://99.99.99.old/svn/company/project/trunk/web'
is not the same repository as
'http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project'
```

Is there way to 'relocate' my Android Studio code from repo A to repo B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the command line and do svn relocate: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html

or inside Android Studio the option it's at the bottom of this menu :VCS->Subversion->Relocate

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in update dialog to Update/Switch repository. You can open it with Ctrl+T shortcut.